# Tools to audit implementation of a Node (Javascript) application

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, security

Assume a substantial (MIT Licence) Open Source (Node) Javascript web application.

I'd like to establish confidence that the application does not leak information over the internet.  One approah would be to read every single line and make sure I understand it.  This sort of detailed code-review feels like overkill.

As the Application is behind a NAT/Firewall, it may be sufficient to establish that the implementation does not initiate any remote connections.  It is important to consider both the obvious direct initiation of connections (TCP/HTTP/HTTPS/FTP/SSH - etc.) in the source itself - and by any of the dependencies... and any by indirect means - for example - involving the client web-browser during operation.

I'm not really worried if the application is insecure in the sense that its access controls are fallible from the network on which access is provided... though I don't object to a heads-up about any clear flaws.

Are there tools that make this sort of assesment straightforward?  Would a sandboxing approach be viable - and, if so, what mecnaism would be suitable to create such a Node sandbox?

Answer (score 1):

This question is surprisingly broad. You seem to be asking:

1. are there any "trojan horses" embedded in my nodejs application or its npm dependencies. Did the developers of the code sneak in any malicious code that might exfiltrate my data?
2. is my nodejs web interface secure against cybercreeps?
3. is my server (hosting my nodejs app) secure against cybercreeps?

The first rule of information security is this: **Nobody can steal information you don't store.** If you don't need it, don't store it.

About the **trojan horse** situation, I have these suggestions about code:

1. Inspect your own code to the extent you can. Looking at the `require()` lines of your code is a good start; it alerts you to your own modules that might use outbound networking.
2. Use `npm audit` to take advantage of crowdsourced inspection of your dependencies.
3. If your source code is on github, they'll do some of that `npm audit` work for you and pester you with emails about vulnerabilities.
4. Rework your nodejs web app to use the [hapi.js framework](https://hapi.dev/#security) instead of what you use now. Developed by paranoiacs at Walmart, it has zero external dependencies.
5. If you have the time and/or money, use a static code analysis tool to inspect your code. Sonarqube, Checkmarx, etc etc.

About rigging up your servers to slow down **exfiltration of data**:

1. Monitor or log the outbound traffic from your server and inspect the logs. [This may help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56453/how-can-i-monitor-all-outgoing-requests-connections-from-my-machine).
2. Set up your outbound firewall rules to disallow traffic that's not part of your application. [Digital Ocean's tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/iptables-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands)  is here. Careful: you can overdo this and break stuff you need.
3. Keep your sensitive data (in a dbms, maybe) on a separate machine from your web applications. Set up access for that machine with a whitelist that only allows your web applications, and nobody else, to connect to it.

About whether your **web interface can repel cybercreeps** while allowing legitimate users:

1. Read up on anti-cybercreep packages like [helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/helmet). Understand them and then use them.
2. Consider attacking your web app every few months with a white-hat hacker's tool like burpscan. That tool costs money. Its developers routinely update it to add test for newly discovered vulnerabilities.  It detects stuff like [these OWASP Top Ten vulnerabilities](https://owasp.org/www-project-top-ten/) and more.
3. Pay attention to your web server logs. (And be aware that web servers facing the public net get many many probes from around the world to see if they're vulnerable.)
4. Check the security of your TLS (https) with [Qualys's SSL Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html).

About whether your **server machines can repel cybercreeps** while allowing legitimate administrative access:

1. Promptly post security updates from your operating system vendor.
2. Lock down your machines. Don't run any services you don't need. Turn off, for example, smtp, ftp, dns, ntp, and nfs services on a web server (the services, not the clients for those services).  These days this is fairly easy because bare-bones server editions of operating systems don't come with any of that stuff installed or running.
3. Use `nmap` to check your servers for open ports, routinely. One of [Digital Ocean's excellent tutorials](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-nmap-to-scan-for-open-ports-on-your-vps) describes this.  For a web server, only the ssh and https ports should be open for the safest setup.
4. Make your public-facing servers "sacrificial". That is, make it so you can build a new copy of the server and its software load from scratch at a moment's notice. That way, if a cybercreep does break into your server, you can just burn it down and start up another one, forcing the creep to start over.
5. Did I mention? Promptly post security updates from your operating system vendor.

Comment: Thanks for this interesting reply.  I admit the question is broad - but, of the three things you think I'm asking, the first of the three is what I'm really trying to tackle.  I will definitely look into npm audit... though it feels like its purpose is finding known vulnerabilities - whereas it feels as if I need to identify 'code capable of remote communication' - and then inspect that in detail.

Comment: The crowdsourced auditing of npm packages definitely looks for packages that have undocumented "telemetry" (== spyware) features in them, and flags those as having serious problems.

Comment: Reassuring info about crowdsourced auditing... I really want to find a way I can do this myself.  I'm a fan of the idea that many eyes find faults faster - but i'm interested in software where my own eyes might be the only ones.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try [Sonarqube](https://www.sonarqube.org/)

I have no experience in installing it, but my workplace use it for checking code quality. 
[it shows something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2IPq.png)

it will show which line of code is bad, and give suggestion on how to fix it.

i remember seeing something related to OWASP in sonarqube, but have not give it a try yet.

Comment: I was aware of sonarqube... I think it would make sense to assist with code-reviews... but... I suspect it isn't the right approach to verifying no information leaks.  For example, a library that dispatches detailed telemety would not likely be considered a security flaw by Sonarqube - but is what I care about finding... if it is present.